# Put data on parent/child component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, axios

I would like to group each **sport** by profile in a slider, i have the idea to put a dynamic value `$sportName` because the data will change each hours.

The problem is, i got no response on my console, i try with : `console.log(data)` still nothing...

[image]

My **Parent.vue** :

```
<template>
  <div>
   <h2>Last 3 activity selected</h2>
    <profile-slider :profiles="categories.sportName1.profiles" />
    <profile-slider :profiles="categories.sportName2.profiles" />
    <profile-slider :profiles="categories.sportName3.profiles" />     
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import profile-slider from '/components/profile-slider.vue'

export default {
components: {
  profile-slider,
},
data() {
return {
  categories: {
    sportName1: {
      profiles: [],
    },
    sportName2: {
      profiles: [],
    },
    sportName3: {
      profiles: [],
    },
   },
  };
 },

async mounted() {
  try {
  const response = await axios.get('/getActivity');
if (response.status !== 200) {
  throw new Error(`Request failed with status ${response.status}`);
}
const data = response.data;
//console.log(data)
data.forEach(category => {
  if (category.sportName === '$sportName') {
    this.categories.sportName1.profiles = category.profiles;
    this.categories.sportName2.profiles = category.profiles;
    this.categories.sportName3.profiles = category.profiles;
   }
   });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } 
 },  
};
</script>
```

My **Child** script : **profile-slider.vue** :

```
<template>
  <div class="swiper mySwiper container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper content">
      <div class="swiper-slide card" v-for="(profile, index) in profiles" :key="index">
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="profileInfo">
          <div class="cardLinear"></div>
              <div class="image">
                <img :src="profile.image" alt=""/>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Swiper from 'swiper'; 

export default {
  props: {
    profiles: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Profiles'
    },
  data() {
    return {
      swiper: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    //allProfiles() {
      //return this.categories.sportName1.profiles;
      //return this.categories.sportName2.profiles;
      //return this.categories.sportName3.profiles;
   //}
  },
}
</script>
```